# calculate the mode for every customer_seg with reference to id (Using R)

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFqie.png)

Hi every one,
Could you please help me on this problem,

I have data set with the features id and customer segment(A,B,C,D) there are duplicate id in the data set.

I want to group by id and to replace the categorical data with mode. I have written the below code for the same -

```
library(dplyr)
Aug_Pay = read.csv("/home/hduser/Desktop/Aug_pay.csv")
#Number of Duplicate id in rows
dup <- Aug_Pay[duplicated(Aug_Pay, by = "id")]
#Number of Unique rows
Unique_Rows <- unique(Aug_Pay, by = "id")
### mode function
getmode <- function(v) {
uniqv <- unique(v)
uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
by_id <- group_by(Aug_Pay, id)
new_frame <- by_id %>% summarise(VAR_2  = getmode(Aug_Pay$cust_value_seg),
                             n = n())
```

By executing the above code the entire column is getting replaced by the mode. Instead i want the duplicate id should be grouped by id and the corresponding categorical data should be replaced by mode.

Regards
Chandan

Comment: show some data or come up with a reproducible example